# Unexpected XML View formatting Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, format, android-linearlayout

After updating Android Studio to 3.5 whenever I auto format code (cmd+opt+l) it changes the order of the view tags inside the xml.
So for example in a `LinearLayout` your views would move around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

`Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML`

Search for `Set from` on the top left.

`Set from -> Predefined Style -> Android`

Don't forget to apply your changes

Hope this helps someone